# Load multiple concatenated JSON objects from stream

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I read a couple of similar questions but didn't find any one related to JObject. Here's the problem: I have a Stream with concatenated JSON objects, i.e:

```
{"key1":"value1"}{"key2":"value2"}{"key3":"value3"}
```

Now, I want to read these objects one by one into JObject. Here's how I tried to do it:

```
public class JsonStreamReader : JsonTextReader
{
    public JsonStreamReader(Stream s) : base(new StreamReader(s)) {}
}

private void LoadJson(Stream s)
{
    var r = new JsonStreamReader(s) { SupportMultipleContent = true };
    var obj = JObject.Load(r);
    // ... get data from JObject ...
}
```

The problem here is that JObject.Load() reads all available data from stream, but parses only first object and discards all the rest.
How do I deal with that?

And just in case of XY-problem (why do I need that):
I want to transfer JSON messages via TCP stream. Because I use raw TCP stream, I need to know the size of message to read it. I decided to write small header with `size` and `message type` before each message, so I can read the header into a small buffer, get the size of the following message and then read it entirely.

Comment: Is there any way that you can wrap your JSON objects into an array and comma-separate them?

Comment: @krillgar so that would be a single object?

Comment: Is that the literal json up there? Most API's with a data format like this deliver the json objects new line delimited so the proper way to handle it is to read it line by line, passing each into JObject.Load (might need a different method) rather than trying to do it all at once.

Comment: Well, a single array so that you can deserialize it to an IEnumerable of your objects. Otherwise you're going to have to come up with a way to parse out the string into the separate objects and convert each into a list. I just tried with a `dynamic`, and was getting a parse error (as expected). Right now, your Stream is invalid JSON.

Comment: @krillgar I strongly suggest against transforming the json pre deserialization. The objects aren't delivered in an array to begin with because it is a stream. The API is designed to be consumed in the manner I described above, re-writing the response is extremely error prone and inefficient.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Oh I absolutely agree. Sorry, I forgot to emphasize how bad of an idea that is. Trying to figure out where the objects end would be a nightmare. My initial suggestion was because I was thinking that the OP was combining several API calls into a single deserialization. If that is the case, then it is very easy to combine them into an array.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by setting SupportMultipleContent on JsonReader to true:

[**Read Multiple Fragments With JsonReader**](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm)

If there is an issue with using JObject.Load with that setting then use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject instead.

Comment: Perfect solution, except one thing: reader reads all available data from the stream. I want it to read only one object (so that stream position would be original position + length of read object) because of two reasons: 1] there may be parts of objects that were not completely received yet; 2] following objects are intended to be read by other layers of messaging protocol.