# How to itrate JSON object?

Tags: c#, json, loops, iteration

I trying to get the id and email list from the JSON. How can i achieve this?

My JSON string is

```
{
"name":"name1",
"username":"name1",
"id":505,
"state":"active",    
"email":"name1@mail.com",
},
 {
"name":"name2",
"username":"name2",
"id":504,
"state":"active",    
"email":"name2@mail.com",
}
```

My code is

```
Dictionary<string, string> engineers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"D:\project\Gitlap\EngineerEmail\jsonlist5.json"))
            {
                using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(r))
                    {

                    JObject o2 = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
                    string id = o2["id"].ToString();
                        string email = o2["email"].ToString();
                        engineers.Add(email, id);
                    }
            }



class UserItems
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
```

I can able to get the first person`s mail ID and ID details. I need to iterate this JSON and get all the mail ID and ID.

I don`t know that how to iterate this JSON. I tried some method from the internet but that was not succeeded.

How can I do?

Comment: That isn't really a proper JSON object, it's multiple independent JSON objects concatenated.  To read all of them with Json.NET, set [`SupportMultipleContent = true`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_SupportMultipleContent.htm) as explained in [Load multiple concatenated JSON objects from stream](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29480032/3744182).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to create class that represent the data in json object for example

```
Class obj
{
    public int Id { get ; set; }
    public string email { get ; set; }
    public string username { get ; set; }
    public string state { get ; set; }
    public string email { get ; set; }
}
```

then

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<obj> list = js.Deserialize<List<obj>>(jsonString);
```

after that you can access  all list items id and email by using foreach

Answer (score 2):

First thing is your JSON input is not valid json, you need to fix it. There are two issues in it. Its not collection of json objects and comma is missing between two objects.
Valid json should look like below.

```
[{
   "name":"name1",
   "username":"name1",
   "id":505,
   "state":"active",    
   "email":"name1@mail.com",
 },
 {
   "name":"name2",
   "username":"name2",
   "id":504,
   "state":"active",    
   "email":"name2@mail.com",
}]
```

Now define a c# class representing your json object.

```
public class User
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

Use JSON.Net library to deserialize it as shown below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(File.Exists("json1.json"))
        {
            string inputJSON = File.ReadAllText("json1.json");

            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputJSON))
            {
                var userList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(inputJSON);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, Yeah i missed **comma** and **class user** in this question but it exists in my code, When i tried by kept "[", "]" in the json sting i get following error **Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.**

Comment: Are you using same code which I gave in answer to deserialize it?

Comment: @PankajKapare Nope, I was tried the code which is in the question.

Comment: Problem with that code is you won't get strongly typed code. Its better to use strongly typed code. However you can still make it work with some modifications.  Problem is with this line JObject o2 = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);  Here you are trying to typecase array to single object.

Comment: You are right I am getting the exception in the line **JObject o2 = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader)** when I add the [,] in the json file.

Answer (score 1):

```
JObject o2 = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
foreach(var obj in o2)
{
string id = obj["id"].ToString();
string Email= obj["Email"].ToString();
engineers.Add(email, id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! for your response. I modified my code but now I get " Cannot applying indexing with [] to an expression of type 'KeyValuePair<string,JToken>' " exception

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [Json.NET NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to accomplish this.

Firstly, create a model to represent your JSON data. Typically I would capitalize the first letter of the property names here, but to keep it consistent with the JSON, they are lower case.

```
public class UserData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

You will need to add a using for Json.NET

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Finally, you can load, and deserialize your data into a **strongly typed** list, which you can then use to populate your engineers dictionary.

```
string datapath = @"D:\project\Gitlap\EngineerEmail\jsonlist5.json";
Dictionary<string, string> engineers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
List<UserData> data = new List<UserData>();

using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(datapath))
{
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();

    data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserData>>(json);

    data.ForEach(engineer => engineers.Add(engineer.email, engineer.id.ToString()));
}
```

As mentioned in another answer, your JSON is also badly formed. This will need correcting before it will deserialize correctly. We just need to add a comma to separate the two objects, and wrap them both in a JSON array, with []

```
[
    {
        "name":"name1",
        "username":"name1",
        "id":505,
        "state":"active",    
        "email":"name1@mail.com"
    },
    {
        "name":"name2",
        "username":"name2",
        "id":504,
        "state":"active",    
        "email":"name2@mail.com"
    }
]
```

## Improvements

As your Id field is an integer, it would be better to change your dictionary from

```
Dictionary<string, string> engineers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

into

```
Dictionary<string, int> engineers = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

You will then be able to simplify your ForEach query slightly. The ForEach can also be moved outside of the using() block.

```
data.ForEach(engineer => 
    engineers.Add(engineer.email, engineer.id));
```

## Improved solution

This includes the improvements above, I've used var for brevity.

```
var datapath = @"D:\project\Gitlap\EngineerEmail\jsonlist5.json";
var engineers = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var data = new List<UserData>();

using (var r = new StreamReader(datapath))
{
    var json = r.ReadToEnd();

    data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserData>>(json);
}

data.ForEach(engineer => 
    engineers.Add(engineer.email, engineer.id));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your helping now it works. thank you.