# Converting JSON to C# Array

Tags: c#, json

i am new to c# and have a little problem. I have a JSON-file that includes some mailadresses. For each mailadress there are 4 fields (name, email[], imprint, info2) in this JSON-file.
I want to convert this into an array or arraylist in my project and I am currently using Newtonsoft.Json to achieve this.

I made a class adress :

```
public class adress
{
    public string name = "";
    public string[]  email = {""};
    public string imprint = "";
    public string info2 = "";
}
```

this is the json:

> {"name":"test1","email":["test1@test.de"],"imprint":"testimprint1 testimprint1","info2":"testinfo1"}
>   {"name":"test2","email":["test2@test.de"],"imprint":"testimprint2 testimprint2","info2":"testinfo2"}
>   {"name":"test3","email":["test3@test.de"],"imprint":"testimprint3 testimprint3","info2":"testinfo3"}

and try converting it like this:

```
List<adress> adresses = new List<adress>();
string json_adress = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Mail\\adresses.json");
adresses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<adress>>(json_adress);
```

I get the following error:

> "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[Mailer.adress]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly."`

Maybe someone can help me to understand this json-thing better?

Comment: @Aryan, No, that's shouldn't cause the said issue

Comment: Just a note: you shouldn't create the list object and then deserialize into this variable. This will create an object that is not used and cause pointless allocations.

Comment: Does your JSON have outer brackets -- `[` and `]` -- and commas between objects?  Without the outer brackets your file isn't a single valid JSON value, it's a concatenated series of JSON values.  See http://www.json.org/ for the correct format.  If your file really consists of concatenated JSON objects, you can use the solution from [Load multiple concatenated JSON objects from stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29477352/3744182).  But please confirm this is what you have since it isn't proper JSON.

Comment: So its better to do it like this: List<adress> adresses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<adress>>(json_adress);??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there but a small mistake. What you supplied is as the following. Please take notice that there are no commas at the seperation.

```
{JSONSTUFF}
{JSONSTUFF}
{JSONSTUFF}
```

But the following says that you want it to be converted to `List<address>` but it is not a list :(

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<adress>>(json_adress);`

So in fact what you need to supply is a list of address,

```
[
    {JSONSTUFF},
    {JSONSTUFF},
    {JSONSTUFF},
]
```

Please do not forget the commas :)

[{"name":"test1","email":["test1@test.de"],"imprint":"testimprint1 testimprint1","info2":"testinfo1"},
{"name":"test2","email":["test2@test.de"],"imprint":"testimprint2 testimprint2","info2":"testinfo2"},
{"name":"test3","email":["test3@test.de"],"imprint":"testimprint3 testimprint3","info2":"testinfo3"}]

Comment: absolutely ... spot on!

Comment: @hendrikruhen, glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are linebreaks after each object in the file:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"your path");
List<adress> adresses = new List<adress>();

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    adresses.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<adress>(line));
}
```