# Read multiple concatenated json objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have a file that contains multiple JSON objects that are not separated by comma :

```
{
  "field" : "value",
  "another_field": "another_value"
} // no comma
{ 
  "field" : "value"
}
```

Each of the objects standalone is a valid json object.

**Is there a way that I can process this file easily?**

1. I know this is NOT a valid json, but unfortunately this file is being generated by a 3rd party tool. I have no option of changing the way the output looks like.
2. I can't open a text editor and smart-insert commas / square brackets before the run, since this is an automated process (I also really don't want to write code that opens the file and manipulates it).

In .NET there's a library that has this exact feature : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29480032/2970729
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_SupportMultipleContent.htm

Is there anything equivalent in Ruby?

Comment: *"I can't open a text editor and smart-insert commas / square brackets before the run*" -- You don't need to open a text editor to edit a file! Why not just run `sed` on the file?

Comment: Are the nested hashes in the files or can assume that adding a `,` after each `}` would we a huge step forwards?

Comment: @TomLord Didn't know this command, looking into it right now. 
Actually I have the option to run bash commands before the processing so it might give a proper solution to my problem, but still wondering whether there's a ruby solution to this

Comment: @spickermann my objects are not complexed and doesn't contain nested objects (currently...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your file is that simple you might want to do something like this:

```
# content = File.read(filename)
content =<<-EOF
  {
    "field" : "value",
    "another_field": "another_value"
  } // no comma
  { 
    "field" : "value"
  }
EOF

require 'json'

JSON.parse("[#{content.gsub(/\}.*?\{/m, '},{')}]")
#=> [{"field"=>"value", "another_field"=>"another_value"}, {"field"=>"value"}]
```

Comment: Works as expected :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The [yajl-ruby](https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby) gem enables processing concatenated JSON in Ruby.  The parser can read from a String or an IO.  Each complete object is yielded to a block.

```rb
require 'yajl'

File.open 'file.json' do |f|
  Yajl.load f do |object|
    # do something with object
  end
end
```

See the [documentation](https://rdoc.info/github/brianmario/yajl-ruby/Yajl%2FParser:parse) for other options (buffer size, symbolized keys, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the data will be valid JSON documents, you can use this method to split the string up into documents, and then parse each document.

```rb
def split_documents(str)
  res = []
  depth = 0
  start = 0
  str.scan(/([{}]|"(?:\\"|[^"])*")/) do |match|
    if match[0] == '{'
      depth += 1
    elsif match[0] == '}'
      depth -= 1
      if depth == 0
        match_start = Regexp.last_match.begin(0)
        res << str[start..match_start]
        start = match_start + 1
      end
    end
  end
  res
end
```

This scans the string for `{`, `}`, or strings. Each time it hits a `{`, it increases the depth by 1. Each time it hits a `}`, is decreases the depth by 1. Every time the depth hits zero, you know you have reached the end of a document because you have balanced braces. The regex has to also match strings so that it doesn't accidentally count braces inside of strings e.g. `{ "foo": "ba}r" }`.