# .NET Sockets how to deal with incoming messages in rapid succession

Tags: c#, json, sockets, tcp, stream

So I'm aiming to write a little multiplayer game but first I'm working on getting a server/client architecture setup that can just send simple messages to oneanother using Sockets and JSON.

Rather quickly I've encountered an issue that when a sender sends two messages in rapid succession the receiver receives them as part of the same stream, even though they are seperated by `flush`es.

The entire `Connection` class looks like this, it is used by both the sender and receiver:

```
namespace Networking
{
    public class Connection
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto };

        private Socket socket;

        private NetworkStream stream;

        /// <summary>
        /// Make a connection with a stream from a socket.
        /// </summary>
        public Connection(Socket socket)
        {
            stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            stream.Close();
            socket.Close();

            stream.Dispose();
            socket.Dispose();
        }

        private object writeLock = new object();

        public void Write(Request request)
        {
            lock (writeLock)
            { 
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    Message message = new Message(null, Messaging.Enums.MessageType.Connect, request);
                    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message, jsonSettings);
                    stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json));
                    stream.Flush();
                }
            }
        }

        public Message Read()
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                do
                {
                    int numBytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    ms.Write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
                } 
                while (stream.DataAvailable);

                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
                string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(json, jsonSettings);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The incoming data and error looks like this:

[image]

I suppose this question isn't 100% specific to C# and .NET but more about how to deal with this problem with sockets in general. Looking for some guidance thanks!

Comment: That's because (TCP) sockets don't *do* messaging. They are a single, continuous stream of bytes. If you want messaging, it's up to *you* to impose some mechanism to separate messages (by some form of message framing, distinct message types with known lengths, etc) or to move to a higher level protocol that already implements those for you.

Comment: Ah, I have implemented a `Message` class but it has an inner object that is designed to be of many different types, e.g. `Connect`, `Move`, `Echo` for the message to contain different information, it was working well as a solution until this occured, can it easily be added onto my solution or is it better to use some library or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load multiple concatenated JSON objects from stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477352/load-multiple-concatenated-json-objects-from-stream)

Comment: Unless you have a specific use case for using low level protocols, I would suggest using a higher level protocol that takes care of many of the issues. gRPC seem popular, but there are many others.

Comment: @DragandDrop that might be useful, I'll have to test it tonight after work.

Comment: @JonasH My reasoning is really that I think sockets are more suitable for a multiplayer game (at least the style I'm making), and not some HTTP protocol like gRPC is (atleast under my understanding) also, as I'm using unity and want to deploy to multiple platforms these packages are less favorable. And lastly I want to do it this way because I enjoy writing code and want to learn more!